# awk assign to multiple variables at once

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying to pull two numerical values out of a string and assign them to variables using `awk` (`gawk` is what I'm using specifically). I want to pull the major and minor version numbers out of a tmux version string into `awk` variables, e.g.:

- input: `tmux 2.8`; `maj == 2` and `min == 8`
- input: `tmux 1.9a`; `maj == 1` and `min == 9`
- input: `tmux 2.10`; `maj == 2` and `min == 10`

Assuming my input comes from `tmux -V` on stdin, I currently have the following:

```
tmux -V | awk '{
                  maj = +gensub(/([0-9]+)\..*/, "\\1", "g", $2);
                  min = +gensub(/.*\.([0-9]+).*/, "\\1", "g", $2);
                  # ...do something with maj and min...
               }'
```

This works, but as many users of tmux know, using `if-shell` in the `.tmux.conf` file (where I hope to use this stuff) can easily lead to *really* long lines in the config file, so I'm wondering if there's a way to combine these two variable assignments into one statement to save space...or any other way to glean these two variables from the input and save space.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
awk '{ maj, min = +gensub(/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+).*/, "\\1 \\2", "g", $2); }'
```

...kind of like in Python, but that particular syntax doesn't exist in `awk`. Is there anything else that's possible?

Note that readability isn't really a concern, just length.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that `gensub` is a `gawk` extension, it won't work with any other `awk` implementation. Also note that the `+` unary operator doesn't force numeric conversion in all `awk` implementations, using `+ 0` is more portable.

Here you could do:

```
tmux -V | awk -F '[ .]' '{maj = $2+0; min = $3+0; print maj, min}'
```

If you don't mind using GNU `awk` extensions, you could also do:

```
tmux -V | awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+' '{maj = $1; min = $2; print maj, min}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanations on compatibility!

Answer (score 12):

Since you're using GNU awk, you can use the 3-arg form of `match()` to store multiple capturing groups:

```
awk '
    match($0, /([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/, m) {maj=m[1]; min=m[2]; print maj, min}
' <<END
tmux 2.8
tmux 1.9a
tmux 2.10
END
```

```
2 8
1 9
2 10
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Answer (score 5):

You can split the version into an array:

```
awk '{ split($2, ver, /[.a-z]/) }'
```

then use `ver[1]` instead of `maj`, `ver[2]` instead of `min`.

Adding `a-z` to the separator removes any lowercase letter from the version number. (The other solutions are better here since they explicitly extract numbers.)

Answer (score 3):

Another user posted this answer, and it later was deleted. I thought it was useful:

Using the `split()` function, split the version string into an array `ver`, then access `ver[1]` and `ver[2]` rather than `maj` and `min`, respectively (or simply store the values in those variables):

```
tmux -V | awk '{ split($2, ver, /[.a-z]/); print ver[1], ver[2] }'
```

The plus here is that `split()` isn't a `gawk` extension (though its optional fourth argument `seps` is).

Comment: +1 but why use `/[.a-z]/` as the third (field separation) argument of the `split` string function, instead of just `"."` ?

Comment: @Cbhihe see the explanation on my answer (which I undeleted since villapx thinks it’s useful, thanks villapx!).